# Excel: Can I use text references without volatility?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

A1 contains `Namedrange,1,23,3,bla`

On the row I split it down to having each of the , delimited entries in its own cell. `B1 =LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1), C1= formula results in 1, D1 = formula results in 23, etc`

The problem is I want to feed the Name to an index function as it without using volatile stuff like indirect.

Any way to do that?

`=Index(THIS_IS_A_NAME_FFS(B1),1,1)` without volatility? +-VBA doesn't matter for me.

How do you suggest to go about it.

I will use part of the remaining numeric data to say what row and col the index should go to such as `=Index(THIS_IS_A_NAME_FFS(B1),C1,D1)`

Comment: Just curious -- what's your reason for wanting to avoid volatile functions?

Comment: I'm using a 10mb worth of entries. Volatility slows down everything to a crawl. And I really don't want to dish out cash for a much more powerful computer to cycle data that I can offload by adjusting my functionality. Currently I'm ignoring the named ranges since i dumped the volatile vba and am using 6 matches similar to this one:=IF(""=L10,"",INDEX($E$1:$E$2500,MATCH(L10,$A$1:$A$2500,0)+0))    //// The document becomes very fast and responsive.

Comment: If Name is in B1 use B1 directly

Comment: You mean you want a non-volatile solution which splits a string into its delimited substrings, e.g. "a, bc, def" into "a", "bc" and "def"?

Comment: @Sam & XOR LX ,     IN A3 do:                      `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`             and then tell me how to use the result as a name :) Clarified it up a bit.

Comment: =Index(B1,1,1) what does this formula give in the cell you put it in, it should give you the name written in B1

Comment: For christ sakes - it resolves to a "#REF!".... Here try this: A1 has 1; A2 has 3; A3 has 5; B1 has 2; B2 has 4; B3 has 6;  D1 has Jesus,1,2,15,bla; D3 has =LEFT(H9,FIND(",",H9)-1) ; and finally D5 has =INDEX(D3,2,2); Jesus is a named range A1:B3... If you do =Index(Jesus,2,2) you get returned cell B2. I need a way for D3 to be interpreted as a name not as text without volatility.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own functions with FUNCTIONS, NOT VBA, as it appears you do, you need to move past where you are now.

It's something we've been able to do since the Excel 4 Macros existed, though during the time that was THE macro language of Excel, we just did it on a macro page. Once it shifted to VBA, we could still use certain ones (not all were meaningful outside the context of a macro page) inside Named Ranges (still can), or, for that matter, simply activate the macro language and still use macro pages, though the concept is to not have actual macros. After all, if doing so, why not use the vastly better VBA for them?

`GET.CELL(41,reference)` was what you used to get a formula's text before `FORMULATEXT()` was added. `IFERROR()` is much easier to use than `ISERROR()`. Now with `LET()` we do not HAVE to use auxiliary Named Range/s except that, since lengths in the user function matter, and additions to the start due to adding to the definitions in the `LET()` add length so it keeps changing as you go, it's not sure how much it eases things.

You can never make `Named Range(B1)` work directly as a function. You still need an `IFERROR()` wrapped around it to intercept the failure of `Named Range(B1)`, extract the parameter/s ("B1" in this case), and hold as its failure mode, the actual formula that will use the parameter/s.

In fact, the main advantages of the not-quite-really-available-to-anyone-in-quantity function `LAMBDA()` are:  1) It will let you enter parameters DIRECTLY in all the manners Excel accepts parameters so you do not have to contort yourself to extract a parameter string and split it into sensible pieces, nor do you have to limit your user to certain types of parameter entry (like, a cell vs. a range, or an address vs. a Named Range, etc.) due to the complexity of taking all possible kinds of parameter entry;  and 2) You need never again make any use of an Excel 4 Macro function, not even `EVALUATE()`, which is good because after saying they could go away forever, any time, for the last 25 years, Excel just added the ability for an organization to not let their Excel seats let those macro commands into their Trust Centers, so the slide to "not enough people use them to be a big enough offended (and screwed then things fail) constituency to matter to us so we are finally ending them firmly and forever" has finally begun.

Hence, `LAMBDA()` will make one's scope wider both in what it can accept and what it can output, and will be extraordinarily easier to write. That last has limited me to writing my own Function functions only maybe 20 times over the years. I bet every spreadsheet I write after (some long-awaited day... er... year) I get `LAMBDA()` will have several. Or more.

Long live them though. If worth the trouble (I remember how happy the boss was when I rolled out `OURLOOKUP()` 20 years ago when he couldn't understand `INDEX/MATCH` well enough to change from `VLOOKUP()` and always found using the wonderful `VLOOKUP/INDEX` almost as hard to understand. It did what `XLOOKUP()` does today, just the three parameters needed, nothing extra, but it took a form of parameters so close to `VLOOKUP()`'s that he got it right off. Most have been for me, hard work to make, but then did things the business needed from me with simple structure.

HOWEVER, while clearly I believe you are after the above, if you truly do want just to take the B1 content and act upon it in a way consistent with whatever text makes up the name of the Named Range, then you can definitely set that up in an `IF()` structure. No need, unless you do something really odd, for `INDIRECT()`.

Without filling us in on just what kind of thing you do with each, the Named Range and the B1 content, I can't be more specific than that without taking 20 feet more of screen space. And since the question comes from 2016, getting more information seems impossibly unlikely...